# Error while doing a very basic test of http server using scala akka spray can

Tags: scala, akka, httpserver, spray

I did a very basic test of spray can using:

- Akka 2.10 2.24
- Scala 2.10.3
- Spray Can 1.3.1
- sbt 0.13
- IntelliJ 13

Here is my code:

```
val myListener: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[TestHttpListener], "httpListener")
IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(myListener, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
```

The `httpListener` reacts to `Http.Connected` with `Http.Register(self)`.

I use sbt to run my code. It fails with an `AbstractMethodError`:

```
[ERROR] [07/12/2014 18:46:48.364] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [ActorSystem(default)] Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: spray.can.HttpManager.akka$actor$ActorLogging$_setter_$log_$eq(Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter;)V
        at akka.actor.ActorLogging$class.$init$(Actor.scala:335)
        at spray.can.HttpManager.<init>(HttpManager.scala:29)
        at spray.can.HttpExt$$anonfun$1.apply(Http.scala:153)
        at spray.can.HttpExt$$anonfun$1.apply(Http.scala:153)
        at akka.actor.TypedCreatorFunctionConsumer.produce(Props.scala:422)
        at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:331)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:534)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:560)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.finishCreate(FaultHandling.scala:135)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.faultCreate(FaultHandling.scala:129)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.faultCreate(ActorCell.scala:338)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.faultRecreate(FaultHandling.scala:58)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.faultRecreate(ActorCell.scala:338)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:428)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:447)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:262)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:218)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:385)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Seems like version of actor logging is different from what spray can expects. Could you try to inspect dependencies in sbt with  `inspect test` or something similar?

Comment: Hello, thanks, that was the issue:  I was not using the suitable version of akka-core dependency for the version of spray I am using.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Added an answer so that other people can easily see what was the correct solution.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala world it's very important to be careful with versions since everything develops rapidly and backwards compatibility between major versions is not guaranteed.

**Spray** depends on **Akka** and [this page](http://spray.io/project-info/current-versions/) contains information regarding supported combinations.

> spray 1.3.1 is built against Scala 2.10.3 and Akka 2.3.0 as well as Scala 2.11.1 and Akka 2.3.2.

So, if you use Scala 2.10.3 the correct version of Akka would be at least 2.3.0.

Moreover, the example which I think you are following from [this](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-can/http-server/) page is not very good.

First of all it misses the fact that the code where you initialise the thing with `IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(...)` must be inside an actor. The actor, which received `Http.Bind` tries to reply with `Http.Bound` and since the caller is not an actor you get dead letters.

So, I would advise to do something like this:

```scala
class MyApp extends Actor {

  implicit val system = context.system

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "start" =>
      val myListener: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[TestHttpListener], "httpListener")
      IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(myListener, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
  }
}
```

Then from the `main()` method of your app you need to do:

```scala
val myApp: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[MyApp], "myApp")
myApp ! "start"
```

Another thing that is not so easy to understand from the example is that in your listener actor you need not only to process messages, but also register itself on every connection:

```scala
class TestHttpListener extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/ping"), _, _, _) =>
      sender() ! HttpResponse(entity = "PONG")

    case c : Tcp.Connected =>
      sender() ! Http.Register(self)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank.  However, I have another problem now :(  The http.Bind failed, and I don't know why either:  an underlying actor is set to deadletter, and some message is not received.  But I guess that's another problem and question...

Comment: @Joel I've added some more information to the answer that might help.

Comment: THANKS.  I don't know how I would have guessed, I am am frustrated that the official doc is wrong!  This techno is interesting, but it's a nightmare. Unfortunately, the binding still fails.  When I write `val myListener: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[TestHttpListener], "httpListener")`, I get a warning on the bind, then a message related to deadletter box.  When I write  `val myListener: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[TestHttpListener], "httpListener")`, I just get the warning without any dead-letter-box problem. I will spend 2 days to just launch an http server :(

Comment: Today it works.  I don't know what I did, since I didn't change the code at all.  But yesterday night I upgraded IntelliJ and SBT plugins.  It seems that IntelliJ has some issues with scala projects.  THANKS A LOT.

Comment: Actually I bumped into a register-timeout error.  Here I am unfamiliar with scala differences:  If I type `case m @ Http.Connected => sender ! Http.Register(self)`, it does not work.  If I type `case _ : Http.Connected => sender ! Http.Register(self)`, it works.  I don't know the semantical differences, that's strange to me.

Comment: Joel, maybe you open another question for this unrelated question. Or, feel free to ask on the spray-user mailing list.

Comment: Btw. usually you don't interact with the messages directly but use the spray-routing layer on top which simplifies writing actual REST services a lot. Have you seen the spray-template project? https://github.com/spray/spray-template/tree/on_spray-can_1.3

Comment: If you use `case m @ Http.Connected => ...` you are matching against the companion object of `Http.Connected` which is an instance which is never actually used.

Comment: @jrudolph Well spotted! Also fixed the example in the answer.